# How to make my HTML, CSS & JavaScript popup responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I've been struggling to make my html, CSS & JavaScript popup responsive. I had a look at similar posts and videos but couldn't find anything that worked on my code. I definitely know it's possible to make it responsive!

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .popup{
        width:100%;
     }
   }
```

Below is my code for the popup

HTML

```
<div class='popup'>     
        <div class='cnt223'>
            <div class="popupCloseButton">&times;</div>
        <h1>Important Notice</h1>
        <p>We were affected by the fire next door and will remain closed until further notice.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function(){
        var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
        overlay.show();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popup').show();
        $('.popupCloseButton').click(function(){
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        return false;
        }); 
         
        $('.x').click(function(){
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        return false;
        });
        });
        
    </script>
```

CSS

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    -moz-opacity:0.7;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    }
    .cnt223 a{
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    .popup{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 101;
    }
    .cnt223{
    min-width: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    min-height: 150px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 103;
    padding: 15px 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #000;
    }
    .cnt223 p{
    clear: both;
        color: #555555;
        /* text-align: justify; */
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    .cnt223 p a{
    color: #d91900;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
    .cnt223 .x{
    float: right;
    height: 35px;
    left: 22px;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    width: 34px;
    }
    .cnt223 .x:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    }

/*--------CLOSE BUTTON--------*/
.popupCloseButton {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #999;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.popupCloseButton:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change some CSS and it work please try it:

```js
$(function(){
        var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
        overlay.show();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popup').show();
        $('.popupCloseButton').click(function(){
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        return false;
        }); 
         
        $('.x').click(function(){
        $('.popup').hide();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
        return false;
        });
        });
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .popup{
        width:calc(100% - 70px);
     }
   }
   #overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    -moz-opacity:0.7;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
    }
    .cnt223 a{
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    .popup{    width: calc(100% - 70px);
    margin: 0 35px;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 101;
    }
    .cnt223{
    min-height: 150px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 103;
    padding: 15px 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #000;
    display: flow-root;
    }
    .cnt223 p{
    clear: both;
        color: #555555;
        /* text-align: justify; */
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    .cnt223 p a{
    color: #d91900;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
    .cnt223 .x{
    float: right;
    height: 35px;
    left: 22px;
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    width: 34px;
    }
    .cnt223 .x:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    }

/*--------CLOSE BUTTON--------*/
.popupCloseButton {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #999;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.popupCloseButton:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='popup'>     
        <div class='cnt223'>
            <div class="popupCloseButton">&times;</div>
        <h1>Important Notice</h1>
        <p>We were affected by the fire next door and will remain closed until further notice.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi there! We added some text on the popup but kept the styling the same. On mobile layout it get's cut off. Please look at this link https://www.saonline.africa/

Comment: I change it and it solved ... you must add `display: flow-root;` to `.cnt223` in css